# XSLT remove attribute if ancestor exists

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to remove an attribute from a node based on the existance of an ancestor by name.

Here's my template. I'm trying to remove all `minOccurrs` attributes except where the ancestor is `updateCurrentObjective`.

```
<xsl:template match="@minOccurs">
    <xsl:if test="0 = count(ancestor::node()[name() = 'updateCurrentObjective'])">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

So for the following XML it should remove the attribute.

```
  <xs:extension base="tns:planElement">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="action" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  <xs:extension>
```

But for the following it should be left intact.

```
  <xs:complexType name="updateCurrentObjective">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="currentObjective" type="tns:objective"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have two template rules:

```
<xsl:template match="@minOccurs"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@name='updateCurrentObjective']//@minOccurs">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to manipulate a schema? In that case I don't think there will be an ancestor with `name() = 'updateCurrentObjective'`, rather there will be an element with `@name = 'updateCurrentObjective'`.

So use

```
<xsl:template match="@minOccurs[not(ancestor::*[@name = 'updateCurrentObjective'])]"/>
```

to avoid copying `minOccurs` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It may also be possible to put the predicate in the template match, but this is beyond me.

I'm also assuming that you are trying to transform the `xsd` itself (and not an instance of a document matching it)

```
   <xsl:template match="@minOccurs">
      <xsl:if test="parent::*[1]//ancestor::*[@name='updateCurrentObjective']">
          <xsl:copy/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Basically, from the element, trace back to the parent element, and then see if any of its ancestors have an attribute `name='updateCurrentObjective'`. More specific element names can be used to replace the `*`'s if you can.